# Graph isomorphism: access local variable globally

Tags: r

I want to print the final answer R outside the loop. And also I want to access only those graph object which are isomorphic. Can any one help?

```
g1 <- graph.ring(10 , directed = FALSE)
g2 <- graph.ring(5 , directed = FALSE)
g3 <- graph.ring(7 , directed = FALSE)
g4 <- graph.ring(6 , directed = FALSE)
g5 <- graph.ring(8 , directed = FALSE)

g <- list(g1,g2,g3,g4,g5)
g 


iso = function(g,i,j)
{ 

   r <- graph.isomorphic(g[[i]],g[[j]])
   return(r)
   print(g[[i]])
   print(g[[j]])
```

}

```
for(i in 1:5)
{
  for(j in 1:5)
   {
      r= iso(g , i , j)
      print(r)
      print(g[[i]])
      print(g[[j]])
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I will try to answer this part:

> i want to print the final answer r outside the loop.

What you want to do is set the variable in the *parent frame* of the loop. This can be done using the `<<-` operator:

```
r <<- iso(g , i , j)
```

Then after the loop you can call:

```
print(r)
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion but it will not working. I just want to access the variable outside the for loop. I found the graph isomorphism using the graph.isomorphic function and take for loop. In graph isomorphism it gives answer in Boolean form TRUE or FALSE. i got that but it will not access globally.